# PHP echo creates extra line in <ul>

Tags: php, html

I'm really new to coding and I'm getting stuck on a blank lines issue.  I've spent two days researching articles on blank lines, white space, etc., and I'm not finding anything that addresses this particular problem.

I have PHP code that is grabbing the contents of a file in my directory.  I output these variables on an HTML page and I have these items scrolling vertically.  Basically, it's a vertical news ticker.  But I'm encountering irregular results.  In IE11 everything works perfectly.  However, in IE9 (where the end users will be viewing the page), the combination of lists with echoed PHP variables creates extra lines between each "li".  So, instead of 5 "articles", I have 9.

Normally I wouldn't care about extra spaces, but the news ticker is treating the extra lines like a "news" item and will pause for the user to read that blank line.  This seems to have something to do with calling php variables via a "ul", but I cannot find anything to remove these extra lines.  Has anyone encountered this?  Or do you have an idea of what I can do to resolve?

```
<div id="content" class="block" style="float:left; position:relative; left:135px;">
<ul id="ticker">
    <li><?php echo $par1;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $par2;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $par3;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $par4;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $par5;?></li>
</ul>
```

Code from Source View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

ul#ticker{
width:700px;
height:200px;
}

ul#ticker li{
font-family:Verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
width:700px;
height:200px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<span style="float:left; left:10px; position:absolute; width:125px; text-align:right;"><b>Current Events:</b></span>
<div id="content" class="block" style="float:left; position:relative; left:135px;">
<ul id="ticker">
    <li><a href = "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/money_latest/~3/VfqbYKimwZE/index.html" target="_blank">Bulgaria tries to contain bank run</li>
    <li><a href = "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/money_latest/~3/EqRCj13Dabw/index.html" target="_blank">GM offers victims more than $1 million</li>
    <li><a href = "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/money_latest/~3/g_ws27zfMkg/index.html" target="_blank">Stock market flirts with new records</li>
    <li><a href = "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/money_latest/~3/iIm8fzJ9rWM/index.html" target="_blank">Enough with Millennials. Here's what Gen X thinks</li>
    <li><a href = "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/money_latest/~3/x1GNhn8SwnM/index.html" target="_blank">Consumer Reports rates some Graco strollers "don't buy"</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo trim($par1)`? But since you've provided no examples of the actual output or inputs, that's just a guess.

Comment: Could you give us the example content of `$par1` and the HTML it generates?  With no input or output to go on, there's not much Stack Overflow can do to help.  See this guide on [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: pls show was `$par1` etc are

Comment: I would guess this issue has more to do with the javascript that is controlling your ticker then the php

Comment: Please post example data as well as the CSS if you have one that defines LI

Comment: I've added the code from the source view.  I completely wasn't thinking about that as a viable option for displaying the output of my PHP code.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled up the developer tools in IE and found that, for some reason, the code as I had it written was creating a secondary list element for each news item.  However, that list element contained only the "a" tag portion of my PHP variable so it wasn't truly blank, although it obviously appeared that way.

I'm not sure why this occurred, but I changed the "ul" to a div tag and the "li" to a p tag and now it's working the way I want it to.  The only question that still leaves me with is why IE11 overlooked the list items that contained only the "a" tags, but IE 9 didn't.  However, that's not a problem I need to answer today.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Because you're not closing the a tags.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard to say from your description. I would suggest perhaps loading the page in IE9, then viewing the source (and posting it here if you don't see the issue).

Also,

> in IE9 (where the end users will be viewing the page)

Are you for real?

Comment: I've added the source, as you requested.  And unfortunately, yes. Corporate software doesn't keep up with Microsoft nearly as well as it should.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.viper-7.com/lw0VuN

here is a fiddle,showing it works. most probably one of your `$par` variables is not defined. best way to avoid this is to make an array and use a foreach http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php , or to check if it is defined like so:

```
<?php if($par1) echo "<li>".$par1."</li>"; ?>
```

and so on. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if the code I added above is helpful.  But my variables are all working correctly when I echo them out in the php portion of my code, and they're also working fine when they're echoed out in the html section on my IE11 page.  It's only in IE9 that I'm having this issue in.